# Select third table with the first condition [SQL]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This SQL is working fine and display only the messages in table gchat where the user is a member in the group

```
SELECT *
FROM gchat 
LEFT JOIN codes ON (gchat.code = codes.code)
WHERE codes.u_username = 'user1'
```

What I need to add, I have also table name (pchat) is considered as private chat between users so also I want to display the messages belong to the 'user1' in the first SQL statement

Table Structure

gchat

```
CREATE TABLE `gchat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fromuser` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

pchat

```
CREATE TABLE `pchat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fromuser` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `touser` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Working fine? Well, it's executing as a regular INNER JOIN. If you want a LEFT JOIN, move the codes.u_username condition from the WHERE clause to the ON clause.

Comment: @jarlh I want to add pchat!

Comment: UNION ALL pchat and chat.

Comment: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
 SELECT gchat.id,gchat.fromuser,gchat.text,gchat.date
 FROM gchat 
 LEFT JOIN codes ON (gchat.code = codes.code)
 WHERE codes.u_username = 'user1'
  UNION
 SELECT id,fromuser,text,date
 FROM pchat 
 WHERE fromuser='user1'
)Z
```

Here i had made two different projection for `gchat` and `pchat` table and using that `UNION` combine all records from both table. For specific user `WHERE` condition used,that will filter out whole bunch of record.

Try this code.Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks but pchat has no column named code only for gchat

Comment: @AbdulazizM Please show table structure of pchat table.

Comment: Is there any link between `codes` and `pchat`? Or I can say `fromuser` from `pchat` may be consider as a  **'user1'**.?

Comment: there is no link between codes and pchat, say touser or fromuser as a 'user1'

Comment: Unknown column 'Z.u_username' in 'where clause'

Comment: It is working fine, well done could you please one more thing, what is about pagination style lets say 25 per 25

Comment: @AbdulazizM Pagination in terms of `CSS` ?

Comment: No don't have idea about same.